# css hover change iframe position and z-index wont work in IE

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a feature on my page when I hover over an `iframe` the css changes the `position` and `z-index` so that the `iframe` gets bigger and moves to the front.  However it wont work in IE. It's difficult to get the hover change to trigger (I have to move slowly over the borders of the div) and when it does trigger the enlarged `iframe` is missing.

JSfiddle for this:  http://jsfiddle.net/LWRUd/  (fiddle works correctly btw)

**CSS:**

```
.server-unit-head{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ccccdd;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-align:left;
    color:blue;
    /*This causes words to wrap on characters as opposed to white spaces*/
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}

.server-unit{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.server-unit:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 50;
}

.server-unit span{ /*CSS for enlarged iframe*/
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ccccff;
    padding: 5px;
    left: -1000px;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.server-unit:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged iframe on hover*/
    visibility: visible;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px; /*position where enlarged iframe should offset horizontally */
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<td class="server-unit-head">
    <p>${serverUnit}</p>
    <div class="server-unit">
        <p><iframe name="iFrameName" height="297" width="297" scrolling="no" src=" ${serverUnit}"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
        <span><iframe name="iFrameName" height="500" width="500" scrolling="yes" src=" ${serverUnit}"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle so we can get a visual on your issue?

Comment: sure.  thanks.  the JSfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/LWRUd/  btw fiddle works correctly

Comment: @RobMcFeely IE old version doesnt support div:hover and In your css you had .server-unit:hover i.e. div:hover.